Smoothing a function on the sphere via convolution
Consider a Lipschitz function $f:S^n\to \mathbb{R}$. Is there a way to construct smooth functions $f_t: S^n\to \mathbb{R}$, such that $$\Vert f_t -f\Vert_\infty\to 0$$ as $t\to 0$? I know that something like this holds for functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, but even if I consider $f$ as defined on (a subset of) $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, that can't be replicated. In the book, Approximation Theory and
Harmonic Analysis on Spheres and Balls they define a sort of convolution formula in Definition 2.1.1 but I don't see how to use that to cook up a family that will converge uniformly. What should be the choice of $g_t$ in that case? What properties will I need for it to work? I believe if $g$ is smooth, then so is $f*g$ as their formula is given. Is that correct? Some suggestions and references will be appreciated.

One way, in line with your first thoughts, is to extend $f$ to the whole of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (for instance by setting $F(x)= |x|^2f(x/|x|)$ or some other way), and then approximating this extension via convolution.

I don't see how you would get a smooth function on the sphere from this method.

Since the sphere is compact, we can directly show smooth functions are dense among continuous functions by Stone-Weierstrass as the subalgebra of smooth functions separate points. This produces a family $f_t$ of smooth functions that are converging uniformly to a given continuous function $f$. This doesn't appeal to the methods of convolution at all, but this also has the disadvantage of not having an explicit form for the $f_t$'s.

What is the meaning of separates points? Can you give an example how to construct such a function?

It's about the diffusion equation in the n-sphere $$\partial_t p(t,a,b) = \Delta_a p(t,a,b).$$ For short times $t>0$ the Laplacian at any point is the local euclidean Laplacian in normal coordinates with the Gausssian as solution.
For finite $t>0$ its the sum over the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian. Symbolically, the time decaying sum  $$p(t,a,b) = \sum_L  e^{-|L|^2 t} \ a_L \ Y_L(a)\ Y_L(b)$$ over the system of eigenvalues and eigenfunction of the Laplacian.
For $t\to 0$ the sum approaches the sum of products of eigenfunctions and translated eigenfunctions, yielding the $\delta$ functional (completeness condition of the eigenfunction system of an elliptic operator).
With $t->\infty$ all modes decay except the 0-mode, the constant distribution over the sphere.

I'm not familiar with diffusion equation but I don't understand how to relate this to the question I asked. Could you be more explicit about how to get a smoothing? Also what are the variables $a,b$ here? I want a function on $S^n$. Could you clarify?

It's only a hint. The study of Greens functions on the unit n-sphere  is in fact group representation theory of $SO(n)$ by eigenfunction spaces of the spherical Laplacian. For me, I understood whats going on only after studying the book 'Heat Kernels and Dirac operators'. Only in SU(n) and Dirac theory representation theory of the rotation group can be done efficiently.  https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-58088-8
